# How can I connect to AWS IoT by using mqtt.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot

The following code reports handshake timeout error. I didn't put exact data on the code but with my own understanding of those params. Is there anything wrong with my understanding?

```js
var options = {
    clientId: a random String,
    endpoint: the endpoint of AWS IoT Core,
    accessKey: I generate this from IAM - > Dashboard - > My access Key - > Access key,
    secretKey: I generate this from IAM - > Dashboard - > My access Key - > Access key,
    regionName: i find this from endpoint,
    debug: true
};


var client = mqtt.connect('ws://' + endpoint, options);
//var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org');
client.on('connect', function() {
    alert("MQTT connected");
    client.subscribe('topic_1')
    client.publish('topic_1', 'Hello mqtt2')
})

client.on('message', function(topic, message) {
    // message is Buffer
    alert(message.toString())
    client.end()
})
```

I wonder if I misunderstand the first param of connect function but I don't know how to change.

My policy is shown as below.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I am sure that I have attached this policy to my certificate.

Comment: "Action": "iot:*", "Resource": "*". These two params are not correctly write in the question. I have chose the *, so I don't think my policy is incorrect

Comment: There is a link under the question to allow you to edit it if needed.

Comment: Ok I rearrange my question

Comment: Some one from other question says it can be : the clientId was not encapsulated in quotes. What's this about?

Comment: The [AWS IoT Core docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html) only mention 'MQTT over WSS" (there is no mention of unsecured `ws`). Try a secured (`mqtt.connect('wss://' + endpoint, options);`) connection.

Comment: After trying 'wss://' + endpoint, it reports WebSocket connection to 'wss:// + endpoint  failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302. What's wrong? I am using mqtt.js v4.0.1, does the version of mqtt.js matter?

Comment: Is the URL you are using in the format `wss://iot-endpoint/mqtt` as per [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html)?

Comment: After changing the URL, the connection will wait for a period of time, but the code: alert("MQTT connected"); does not response. Then the error is arised, WebSocket connection to 'wss:// + endpoint + '/mqtt' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED

Comment: Now, I added the port 443,  the url is like wss://iot-endpoint:443/mqtt. But I can't see my message in AWS Test part. Should this be a normal situation?